# CSS Div Positions

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in html and im clueless, i apologize if i seem ignorant.

In this picture example am I supposed to use absolute position or relative for the containers

[image]

and how many total containers do I need to make

This is the code i currently have:

```html
 <div style="border-style: solid;border-color:blue;">
     <div>
      <img id="logo"src="insta.jpg">
      <img id="logo"src="twitter.png">
      <img id="logo"src="facebook.png">
            <br>
         <br> 
      <img style="float:left;"src="u1.png">
      <p> <strong> Ali Omar <br> November 13,2017 </strong> </p>
      <br>
      <p> The important difference is that floated elements still remain a part of the "flow" of the page where absolutely positioned elements do that. 
      As such, they can be more than "flexible" choice. </p>
     </div>
      
      
     <div style="position:absolute;border-style: solid;border-color:orange;">
         <br>
      <img style="float:left;"src="u2.png">
      <p> <strong> Guest <br> November 13,2017 <br> Hi Ali,,, </strong> </p>
      <br>
      <p> When i'm increasing a window size, the div container is not fixed in a particular position, I also used an absolute position, but it is not working. help me </p>
     </div>
     
    </div>
```

In addition ,the 2nd division container is not included in the first one with its border, what could be causing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5s0u3vzf/1/)

```css
.first {
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.first img {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

.second {
  position: relative;
}
.second img {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
 <div style="border-style: solid;border-color:blue;">
     <div class="icon" style="float:right">
      <img id="logo"src="https://www.circle-cafe.com/files/social-icons/in.svg">
      <img id="logo"src="https://ugihvac.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/twitter_icon.png">
      <img id="logo"src="http://saconnects.org/wp-content/uploads/Facebook-icon-e1447702821330.png">
      </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="first">
      <img style="float:left;"src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/17241-200.png">
      <p> <strong> Ali Omar <br> November 13,2017 </strong> </p>
      <br>
      <p> The important difference is that floated elements still remain a part of the "flow" of the page where absolutely positioned elements do that. 
      As such, they can be more than "flexible" choice. </p>
        </div>
      
      
     <div class="second" style="border-style: solid;border-color:orange;">
         <br>
      <img style="float:left;"src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/17241-200.png">
      <p> <strong> Guest <br> November 13,2017 <br> Hi Ali,,, </strong> </p>
      <br>
      <p> When i'm increasing a window size, the div container is not fixed in a particular position, I also used an absolute position, but it is not working. help me </p>
     </div>
      <br>
    </div>
```

Comment: That did the trick, if id like to add another container beneath them within the main one with blue border, that is relative to the main one in terms of position, how do i get to do that

Comment: I've made a div with the following code and this is how it looks like `<div style="border-style: solid;border-color:orange;">
   <br>
   <img id="logo" style="float:left;" src="send.png">
   <img id="logo" style="float:left;" src="cancel.png">
     </div>`

Comment: im edit my answer. you can edit in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5s0u3vzf/1/). not yet for image.

Comment: That's astounding! thanks a lot for your effort, that helped me immensely in terms of syntax and other alternative attributes such as classes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Positioning an element as absolute requires that some of its containers has a `position: relative` property. The relative postioned container will work as *field of reference* for the absolute positioned element. So just add `position: relative` to the parent container as in the code below.
Do you really want

```html
<div style="border-style: solid; border-color:blue; position: relative">
     <div>
      <img id="logo"src="insta.jpg">
      <img id="logo"src="twitter.png">
      <img id="logo"src="facebook.png">
            <br>
         <br> 
      <img src="u1.png">
      <p> <strong> Ali Omar <br> November 13,2017 </strong> </p>
      <br>
      <p> The important difference is that floated elements still remain a part of the "flow" of the page where absolutely positioned elements do that. 
      As such, they can be more than "flexible" choice. </p>
     </div>
      
      
     <div style="position:absolute;border-style: solid;border-color:orange;">
         <br>
      <img style="float:left;" src="u2.png">
      <p> <strong> Guest <br> November 13,2017 <br> Hi Ali,,, </strong> </p>
      <br>
      <p> When i'm increasing a window size, the div container is not fixed in a particular position, I also used an absolute position, but it is not working. help me </p>
     </div>
     
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div style="border-style: solid;border-color:blue;">
    <div> <img id="logo" src="insta.jpg"> <img id="logo" src="twitter.png"> <img id="logo" src="facebook.png">

        <br>
        <br> <img style="float:left;" src="u1.png">
        <p> <strong> Ali Omar <br> November 13,2017 </strong> </p>
        <br>
        <p> The important difference is that floated elements still remain a part of the "flow" of the page where absolutely positioned elements do that. As such, they can be more than "flexible" choice. </p>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; right :0px; left: 0px; border-style: solid;border-color:orange;">
        <br>
        <img style="float:left;" src="u2.png">
        <p> <strong> Guest <br> November 13,2017 <br> Hi Ali,,, </strong> </p> <br>
        <p> When i'm increasing a window size, the div container is not fixed in a particular position, I also used an absolute position, but it is not working. help me </p>
    </div>
</div>
```